# Use $timeout to wait service data resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to pass data from directive to controller via service, my service looks like this:

```
angular
    .module('App')
    .factory('WizardDataService', WizardDataService);

WizardDataService.$inject = [];

function WizardDataService() {
    var wizardFormData = {};

    var setWizardData = function (newFormData) {
        console.log("wizardFormData: " + JSON.stringify(wizardFormData));
        wizardFormData = newFormData;
    };

    var getWizardData = function () {
        return wizardFormData;
    };

    var resetWizardData = function () {
        //To be called when the data stored needs to be discarded
        wizardFormData = {};
    };

    return {
        setWizardData: setWizardData,
        getWizardData: getWizardData,
        resetWizardData: resetWizardData
    };
}
```

But when I try to get data from controller it is not resolved (I think it waits digest loop to finish), So I have to use $timeout function in my controller to wait until it is finished, like this:

```
$timeout(function(){
    //any code in here will automatically have an apply run afterwards
    vm.getStoredData = WizardDataService.getWizardData();

    $scope.$watchCollection(function () {
        console.log("getStoredData callback: " + JSON.stringify(vm.getStoredData));
        return vm.getStoredData;
    }, function () {
    });
}, 300);
```

Despite of the fact that it works, what I am interested in is, if there is a better way to do this, also if this is bug free and the main question, why we use 300 delay and not 100 (for example) for $timeout and if it always will work (maybe for someone it took more time than 300 to get data from the service).

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise from your service get method.  Then in your controller, you can provide a success method to assign the results.  Your service would look like this:

```
    function getWizardData() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http.get("/myserver/getWizardData")
            .then(function (results) {
                deferred.resolve(results.data);
            }),
            function () {
                deferred.reject();
            }
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

And in your ng-controller you call your service:

```
wizardService.getWizardData()
     .then(function (results) {
        $scope.myData = results;
     },
     function () { });
```

No timeouts necessary.  If your server is RESTFULL, then use $resource and bind directly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't have server or URL here, I am just adding data(object) to the service with setWizardData method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular.copy` to replace the data without changing the object reference.

```
function WizardDataService() {
    var wizardFormData = {};

    var setWizardData = function (newFormData) {
        console.log("wizardFormData: " + JSON.stringify(wizardFormData));
        angular.copy(newFormData, wizardFormData);
    };
```

From the Docs:

> ### angular.copy
>
> Creates a deep copy of source, which should be an object or an array.
>
> - If a destination is provided, all of its elements (for arrays) or properties (for objects) are deleted and then all elements/properties from the source are copied to it.
>
> ## Usage
>
> ```
>  angular.copy(source, [destination]);
> ```

-- [AngularJS angular.copy API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy)

This way the object reference remains the same and any clients that have that reference will get updated. There is no need to fetch a new object reference on every update.